# Connect to sample SOAP 1.1 with PHP For CEBROKER

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nsnetservicebrowser

I need to connect to CEBroker SOAP web services in php. The SOAP request is:

```
POST /CEBrokerWebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: test.ws.cebroker.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.cebroker.com/CEBrokerWebService/TestUploadXMLFile"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestUploadXMLFile xmlns="http://www.cebroker.com/CEBrokerWebService/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my code so far,

```
<?php
$username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$options = array(
    "login" => $username,
    "password" => $password,
    'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
);

$client = new SoapClient('test.ws.cebroker.com//CEBrokerWebService.asmx?ws‌​dl', $options);

echo "<pre>";
//print_r($client);die();

$response = $client->TestUploadXMLFile(array(
    "licensee_profession" => 'Licensed Practical Nurse',
    "licensee_number"     => '6547852-25',
    "cebroker_state"      => 'AR',
    "first_name"          => 'Dalton',
    "last_name"           => 'Developer',
    "date_completed"      => '2017-04-06 22:52:16',
));

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Please, post some code

Comment: this is a response of this webservices HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestUploadXMLFileResponse xmlns="http://www.cebroker.com/CEBrokerWebService/">
      <TestUploadXMLFileResult>xml</TestUploadXMLFileResult>
    </TestUploadXMLFileResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: can you see this link : http://test.ws.cebroker.com/CEBrokerWebService.asmx?op=TestUploadXMLDocument

Comment: please post some php code

Comment: $username = "xxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$options = array ("login"=>$username, "password"=>$password, 'use' => SOAP_LITERAL);
$client = new SoapClient('http://test.ws.cebroker.com//CEBrokerWebService.asmx?wsdl' , $options);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($client);die();

$response = $client->TestUploadXMLFile(array(
 "licensee_profession"=> 'Licensed Practical Nurse',
 "licensee_number"=> '6547852-25',
 "cebroker_state"=> 'AR',
 "first_name"=> 'Dalton',
 "last_name"=> 'Developer',
 "date_completed"=> '2017-04-06 22:52:16',
));

print_r($response);

Comment: Perfect, what is the question about the php code? Please read the following tutorial "How to ask" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask